# ¿Cómo mostrar una cadena en emu8086?

Tags: emulación

En la cadena almacene entradas de teclado de usuario, e intento mostrarlo así:
mostrar:

```
org 100h

.data

    mensaje          db 10,13,"La palabra es" 
    mensaje2          db 10,13,"Codificada es","$"
    palabra          db 100 dup(0)  
    codificada       db 100 dup(0)

.code        
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds, ax    
    mov di, 00h
    mov si, 00h
    mov cx, 100



    codificar: 

        call read
.   
        cmp al, 13
        je mostrar 

        mov palabra[si],al 
        inc si    

    algoritmo:
        cmp al,"m"
        je esM
        cmp al,"u"
        je esU
        cmp al,"r"
        je esR
        cmp al,"c"
        je esC
        cmp al,"i"
        je essI
        cmp al,"e"
        je esE
        cmp al,"l"
        je esL
        cmp al,"a"
        je esA
        cmp al,"g"
        je esG
        cmp al,"o"
        je esO
        jmp else
        ret

        esM: 
            mov codificada[di],"0"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esU: 
            mov codificada[di],"1"
            inc di
            jmp codificar      

        esR: 
            mov codificada[di],"2"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esC: 
            mov codificada[di],"3"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        essI: 
            mov codificada[di],"4"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esE: 
            mov codificada[di],"5"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esL: 
            mov codificada[di],"6"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esA: 
            mov codificada[di],"7"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esG: 
            mov codificada[di],"8"
            inc di
            jmp codificar

        esO: 
            mov codificada[di],"9"
            inc di
            jmp codificar


        else:
            mov codificada[di],al
            inc di
            jmp codificar




    read:
        mov ah,01h
        int 21h
        ret


    mostrar: 

       mov dx, offset mensaje
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h   

       mov dx, offset[palabra]
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h   

       mov dx, offset mensaje2
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h   

       mov dx, offset[codificada]
       mov ah, 09h
       int 21h




ret
```

Pero no me muestra el contenido de las cadenas

Comment: Te muestra algún tipo de error?, deberías agregar tu declaración de variables.

Comment: no me muestra ningún error, solo no salen los arreglos

Comment: Agrega el resto de tu código para que pueda ayudarte, si estas guardando las cadenas correctamente no deberías tener ningún problema.

Comment: Ya agregue mi código completo.

Comment: Ahh.. ahí esta el detalle, en tu declaración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que la imprimir la cadena en pantalla no indicas el final de esta, la interrupción **21h** con la funcion **09h** imprime en pantalla caracteres hasta que se encuentra con el caracter que le le indica el final de la misma, en este caso es "*$*" o 24h.

Solo debes de agregarlo al termino de cada variable que declaras, de modo que quede así:

```
    mensaje          db 10,13,"La palabra es", "$" 
    mensaje2         db 10,13,"Codificada es", "$"
    palabra          db 100 dup(0), "$" 
    codificada       db 100 dup(0), "$"
```

Lo he probado yo mismo y funciona, espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias!